# 'Assigning a player in multiplayer game' firebase example is not very scalable or is it?

Tags: firebase

In the firebase example (https://gist.github.com/anantn/4323981), to add an user to the game, we attach the transaction method to playerListRef. Now, every time firebase attempts to update data, it will call the callback passed to the transaction method with the list of userid of all players. If my game supports thousands of users to join at a time, every instance this method executes, the entire user list will be downloaded and passed which will be bad.
If this is true, what is the recommended way to assign users then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is specifically what Firebase was designed to handle. If your application needs to actually assign player numbers, this example is the way to go. Otherwise, if the players just need to be in the same "game" or "room" without any notion of ordering you could remove the transaction code to speed things up a bit. The snippet as well as the backend have handled the number of concurrent connections you've mentioned—if you're seeing any specific problems with your code or behavior with Firebase that appears to be a bug, please contact us at support@firebase.com and we can dig into it.